# Calculating time until end of year python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have stock price data for every weekday for the past 50 years, including the date/timestamp. At the end of each month I need to calculate the remaining days until the end of the year. Leap years must be considered since the solution has to use the time stamp. I tried this code:

```
from datetime import datetime 
t = df.index
dfa =(datetime(t.year, 12, 31) -t)/(datetime(t.year, 12, 31)-datetime(t.year, 1, 1))
```

However, it returns the TypeError:

> only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I also tried this:

```
i=0
df["time_value"] = 0
while i<len(df):
    t = df.index[i]
    time_value=(datetime(t.year, 12, 31) -t)/(datetime(t.year, 12, 31)-datetime(t.year, 1, 1))
    df.time_value[i] = time_value
    i+1
```

This is a short example of the dataframe used:

```
              CLOSE_SPX    Close_iBoxx  A_Returns  B_Returns  A_Vola    B_Vola
2014-05-15    1870.85      234.3017    -0.009362   0.003412   0.170535  0.075468   
2014-05-16    1877.86      234.0216     0.003747  -0.001195   0.170153  0.075378
2014-05-19    1885.08      233.7717     0.003845  -0.001068   0.170059  0.075384   
2014-05-20    1872.83      234.2596    -0.006498   0.002087   0.170135  0.075410   
2014-05-21    1888.03      233.9101     0.008116  -0.001492   0.169560  0.075326   
2014-05-22    1892.49      233.5429     0.002362  -0.001570   0.169370  0.075341   
2014-05-23    1900.53      233.8605     0.004248   0.001360   0.168716  0.075333   
2014-05-27    1911.91      234.0368     0.005988   0.000754   0.168797  0.075294   
2014-05-28    1909.78      235.4454    -0.001114   0.006019   0.168805  0.075474   
2014-05-29    1920.03      235.1813     0.005367  -0.001122   0.168866  0.075451   
2014-05-30    1923.57      235.2161     0.001844   0.000148   0.168844  0.075430   
2014-06-02    1924.97      233.8868     0.000728  -0.005651   0.168528  0.075641   
2014-06-03    1924.24      232.9049    -0.000379  -0.004198   0.167852  0.075267
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580227/find-time-until-a-date-in-python.  In fact this is close to a duplicate.

Comment: thanks for the advice, so how would you do it?

Comment: Is `CLOSE_SPX` a [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)?

Comment: What is df in your examples?

Comment: The dates used under "Date" are a datetime index, df is the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) capability which simplifies such a calculation.  You can access the `YearEnd` offset with `pd.datetools.YearEnd()`. Create a new column `'d'` to work on. To each value in this column add the `YearEnd` offset. Then subtract the original date from the sum  to give the number of days to the end of the year:

```
import pandas as pd
df['d'] = df.index 
df['days'] = df.apply(lambda i: i['d'] + pd.datetools.YearEnd() - i['d'], axis=1)
```

You don't need to create a new 'days' column, you can just overwrite the column 'd' if you wish.

`print df['days']` will yield:

```
2014-05-15   230 days
2014-05-16   229 days
2014-05-19   226 days
2014-05-20   225 days
2014-05-21   224 days
2014-05-22   223 days
2014-05-23   222 days
2014-05-27   218 days
2014-05-28   217 days
2014-05-29   216 days
2014-05-30   215 days
2014-06-02   212 days
2014-06-03   211 days
```

If your`index` is not in `DateTime` format then convert with `pd.to_datetime` or use `parse_dates=True` when you load your file.